# Overriding GroupAdmin class

Tags: php, symfony

I try to override my SonataUserBundle GroupAdmin Class, like that :

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin as MyGroupAdmin;

class GroupAdmin extends MyGroupAdmin
{
...
}
```

And add parameters in my config.yml file :

```
parameters:
    sonata.user.admin.group.class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin
```

But when I try to view my form I have that exception:
Attempted to load class "GroupAdmin" from namespace "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Document\GroupAdmin", "Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\GroupAdmin" or "Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin"?

My kernel :

```
$bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),

            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),

            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MarkdownBundle\KnpMarkdownBundle(),
            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
            new Sonata\FormatterBundle\SonataFormatterBundle(),

            new Sonata\NewsBundle\SonataNewsBundle(),
            new Sonata\MediaBundle\SonataMediaBundle(),
            new Sonata\IntlBundle\SonataIntlBundle(),
            new Sonata\ClassificationBundle\SonataClassificationBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),
            new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),
            new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle(),

            new Application\Sonata\NewsBundle\ApplicationSonataNewsBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\UserBundle\ApplicationSonataUserBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\ApplicationSonataMediaBundle(),
            new Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\ApplicationSonataClassificationBundle(),
        );
```

This is 6:00 and I can't find the error. Plz help

Comment: You have  two Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin classes.

Why would you extend the class in the same namespace ?

Comment: I have one GroupAdmin class in Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin and another in Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\GroupAdmin with a different namespace... I need to use that to overrid the original.

Comment: My bad i thought it was the same namespaces.Is the `Application`  namespace properly registered in the autoload ?Do you have other classes in that namespace that work ?

Comment: No the only class in that namespace.. I already start to develop a new app

Comment: I edited my post and added kernel content

Comment: Did you use the generate bundle command for these bundles ?

Comment: yes. My bad, I have just to add .php extension to my file. Now it works :D

Comment: I added it as answer so that others may benefit from it.Feel free to upvote and/or accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is not a problem with the class declaration or the error would contain 'The file was found but the class was not in it'.

You most likely have a typo in the name of the file